# Netbeans says class does not exist in FXML file for observablearrayList but it does

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, fxml

I have this FXML file generated by Netbeans (but I have modified the TableColumn bit):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="MainPane" prefHeight="529.0" prefWidth="513.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="d1example2.UserInterfaceController">
  <children>
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.17835671342685372" focusTraversable="true" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="501.0" prefWidth="485.0">
      <items>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
          <children>
            <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="32.0">
              <children>
                <TextField fx:id="FirstField" layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" prefWidth="51.0" />
                <Text fx:id="TimesText" layoutX="65.0" layoutY="16.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="*" />
                <TextField id="FirstField" layoutX="90.0" layoutY="0.0" prefWidth="51.0" />
                <Text fx:id="EqualSign" layoutX="168.0" layoutY="16.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="=" />
                <Text fx:id="EquationResult" layoutX="245.0" layoutY="16.0" scaleX="1.632154219166214E8" scaleY="1.436917974231407" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="" />
              </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <Button fx:id="SubmitButton" layoutX="356.0" layoutY="32.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction" text="Submit" />
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
          <children>
            <TableView layoutX="13.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="379.0" prefWidth="456.0">
              <columns>
     <TableColumn text="Half Value">
        <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="HalfContent" />
        </cellValueFactory>
     </TableColumn>
     <TableColumn text="Double Value">
        <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="DoubleContent" />
        </cellValueFactory>
     </TableColumn>
</columns> 
              <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                <Data HalfContent="First Column Text" DoubleContent="Second Column Text" />
            </FXCollections>
            </items>
            </TableView>
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </items>
    </SplitPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And this other class called "Data" which looks like this:

```
package d1example2;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author zmeshign
 */
public final class Data {
   private final SimpleStringProperty HalfContent = new SimpleStringProperty("");
   private final SimpleStringProperty DoubleContent = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public Data() {
        this("", "");
    }

    public Data(String HalfContent, String DoubleContent) {
        setHalfContent(HalfContent);
        setDoubleContent(DoubleContent);
    }

    public String getHalfContent() {
        return HalfContent.get();
    }

    public void setHalfContent(String hContent) {
        HalfContent.set(hContent);
    }

    public String getDoubleContent() {
        return DoubleContent.get();
    }

    public void setDoubleContent(String dContent) {
        DoubleContent.set(dContent);
    }

}
```

So in this line:

```
<Data HalfContent="First Column Text" DoubleContent="Second Column Text" />
```

it says that the class "Data" does not exist while I have it under the same package. All I'm trying to do is to learn how to display a string under a column in a TableView.

I would immensely appreciate any help!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*How to fix it*

In your case the appropriate directive you need to add to the FXML file in order for it to find your `Data` class is:

```
<?import d1example2.Data?>
```

*Why it was failing for you*

FXML files are just files, they are not compiled to Java classes (at least not in the JavaFX 2.2 version).  This means that the files themselves aren't really aware of what package they are in (as packaging is a Java concept).  The FXML files can be told where to locate the Java classes they need though.  To do this you use the `<?import java.lang.*?>` directive at the top of the file (substituting your package name to perform the appropriate import).

---

*Update based on additional question*

> This fixed the problem with the "data" part, but now it's saying: Class d1example2.Data does not support property "HalfContent". It also says this with "DoubleContent".

You need to follow Java property naming conventions.  Under these conventions property names start with a lower case letter rather than an uppercase letter, so use `halfContent` and `doubleContent` as your property names in FXML.

Instead of:

```
<Data HalfContent="First Column Text" DoubleContent="Second Column Text" />
```

Write:

```
<Data halfContent="First Column Text" doubleContent="Second Column Text" />
```

Additionally, you might want to define property accessors for your properties:

```
public StringProperty halfContentProperty() {
    return halfContent;
}
. . .
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed the problem with the "data" part, but now it's saying: Class d1example2.Data does not support property "HalfContent". It also says this with "DoubleContent". What have I done wrong here? Thanks again and I appreciate your help!

Comment: I added an update to the answer to address your additional question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I changed the first letter of both of them to lowercase and also added property accessors for both as well, but it is still giving the same "Class d1example2.Data does not support property halfContent" with the 2 of them. Is there anything else I need to do that I haven't done or any mistakes I've made? Thanks again for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, I think I was too tired! There were still some properties left in the FXML that started with uppercase. I replaced them all with the correct format and that fixed the problem. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's not relevant here but another reason this error arises in NetBeans is where you write something like fx:controller="myPackage.myController.java" in your FXML file. The error being that it's the class name, not the file name containing that class, that is expected.